# How to add animation to the display none -> block in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a code which is exposing and hiding the button

HTML

```
<div id="butStyle">
     <button id="langBut">Язык</button>
     <button id="en"><img src="image/en.png" alt="en" height="20px" width="30px"></button>
</div>
```

JS

```
document.getElementById('en').style.display = 'none';

function displayONLang(){
    document.getElementById('en').style.display = 'block';
}
function displayOFFLang(){
    document.getElementById('en').style.display = 'none';
}
document.getElementById("butStyle").addEventListener("mouseover",displayONLang); 
document.getElementById("butStyle").addEventListener("mouseout",displayOFFLang);
```

So i need to add the smooth animation to this process with javascript, but idk how
Any suggestions?

Comment: Transition does not work when you toggle display property, so I think you should consider using CSS animations

Comment: use css transtion but with opacity 0 instead of display none.
something like this:
#butStyle {
    transtion: all 0.3s;
    opacity:0;
}
#butStyle:hover{
   opacity:1;
}

Comment: @IvanBeliakov There is no way to solve it with JS or maybe with JQuery?

Comment: @Arsen Mkrtumian Do you have to use `display: none` or 0 opacity is also OK?

Comment: Opacity 0 is also okay, the main purpose is to solve it with Javascript

Comment: Smooth transition means CSS styles anyway. Javascript implementation means changing CSS styles, but inside Javascript code :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest approach would be to fade in/out so instead of using `display` as it can't be animated, you could animate either width/height or opacity.

Here's code with solution by animating opacity:

```
document.getElementById('en').style.opacity = '0';
document.getElementById('en').style.transition = '250ms opacity ease';

function displayONLang(){
    document.getElementById('en').style.opacity = '1';
}
function displayOFFLang(){
    document.getElementById('en').style.opacity = '0';
}
document.getElementById("butStyle").addEventListener("mouseover",displayONLang); 
document.getElementById("butStyle").addEventListener("mouseout",displayOFFLang);
```

In this code in the second line I also added transition mode which you can customize to your liking:

```
document.getElementById('en').style.transition = '250ms opacity ease';
```

This is a CSS attribute that allows for smooth transitions between states, you can read more about it [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transition).